# Run shell command in yaml kubernetes stopped container

Tags: shell, kubernetes

I have some issue with kubernetes yaml.

I want to execute touch to make file and copy it to a folder but the container stopped.

```
containers:
  - name: 1st
    image: alpine
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sharedvolume
      mountPath: /usr/share/sharedvolume
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "cd ~/ && touch file.txt && cp file.txt /usr/share/sharedvolume"]
```

I googled through many stackoverflow answers and tried them but nothing worked. I also tried to combine the args on commands but still didn't work.

Comment: That `command:` and `args:` looks like it should in fact copy a file and exit successfully; if the pod has a normal restart policy then Kubernetes will keep restarting it and it will go into CrashLoopBackOff state.  What should the pod actually do; if the container wasn't stopped then what process would it be running?

Comment: @DavidMaze i want it to start normally after the creating file and copy, do i need to add something?

Comment: i see volumeMounts , But not volumes section ? Have you defined volumes setion in your yaml file ?

Comment: You need to somehow launch the entrypoint and/or command the container would have normally run.  In general, sharing volumes between Kubernetes pods is more challenging than it looks and other approaches tend to work better.  For this setup, could you put the file in a ConfigMap instead of manually `cp`ing it at startup time?  If not, the best approach might be to update the image's entrypoint wrapper script to do this `cp` before it `exec "$@"` to run the container command.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please keep in mind that a container exits when its main process exits.
After container in a Pod exits, the `kubelet` restarts it or not depending on the `spec.restartPolicy` field of the Pod (see: [Container restart policy documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy)).

---

As a workaround, you can try adding the `sleep infinity` command to the end of the `args` field (it should work in most cases).

Take a look at the example below:
**NOTE:** I just want you to pay attention to the `sleep infinity` at the end of the `args` filed.

```
$ cat alpine.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: alpine
  name: alpine
spec:
  containers:
  - image: alpine
    name: alpine
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "cd ~/ && touch file.txt && cp file.txt /usr/share/sharedvolume && sleep infinity"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sharedvolume
      mountPath: /usr/share/sharedvolume
...

$ kubectl apply -f alpine.yml
pod/alpine created

$ kubectl get pods
NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
alpine   1/1     Running   0          12s

$ kubectl exec -it alpine -- sh

/ # df -h | grep "/usr/share/sharedvolume"
/dev/sdb                  7.8G     36.0M      7.8G   0% /usr/share/sharedvolume

/ # ls /usr/share/sharedvolume
file.txt    lost+found
```

As you can see the `alpine` Pod is running, so it works as expected.

---

As I wrote before, adding the `sleep infinity` is a kind of workaround. It's worth considering what the main process of this container should be.
Useful information on how to use the `alpine` image can be found in the [How to use this image reference](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor i used while true; do and then put sleep 1; . and its working